# Question on limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\large \frac{\sin^2{x^{2}}}{x^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I solve the following trig equations?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2{x^{2}}}{x^{2}}$$

I am thinking the limit would be zero but I am not sure.

Comment: use l'Hospital's rule you should see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 12, accepted):

---

We use $\;\sin^2(x^2) = (\sin x^2)(\sin x^2)$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}\;=\;\lim_{x \to 0}\; (\sin x^2) \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \sin x^2 \cdot 1 = 0$$

***Recall***, *we're also using the fact* that $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} = 1$. Here, $t = x^2$.

---

Comment: I see so basically to solve you factor out sin^2?

Comment: Yes, exactly: $\sin^2 x^2 = (\sin x^2) \cdot (\sin x^2)$

Comment: It makes sense thanks

Comment: I understand it perfectly now.

Answer (score 16):

I think you want
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x^2}{x^2}.$$
Rewrite our function as 
$$\left(\sin x^2\right) \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}.$$
Now is it easy? Yes, indeed the limit is $0$.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope that soon you will have some knowledge of LaTeX, so that your questions may be easily understood.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin^{2} x^2}{x^2} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 t }{t}$$ which is equal to $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t \sin t \cdot t}{t\cdot t} = \lim _{t\to0} \frac{\sin t}{t} \lim _{t\to0} \frac{\sin t}{t} \lim _{t\to 0} t = 1\cdot 1 \cdot 0 =0$$

Comment: +1, just add a line for let $t=x^2$ and don't bother multiplying by $\frac {t}{t}$, substitution should be more than enough, PS: this answer is the only one making use of substitution nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution, via the Sandwich theorem: We know that $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ for every $x$. Thus, whenever $x\neq 0$ we have 
$$
0\leq\left|\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}\right| =  \frac{\left|\sin(x^2)\right|\cdot\left|\sin(x^2)\right|}{x^2} \leq \frac{x^2\cdot x^2}{x^2}=x^2 .
$$
Now since $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2=\lim_{x\to 0}0=0$, the Sandwich rule gives that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We use $$\sin^2 x =\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x^2}{x^2}.=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-\cos 2x^2}{2x^2}=0  $$

Comment: This is correct, but:(1) please do not write with giant fonts, and (2) don't overuse colours as this can be distracting. Perhaps you should edit your answer. @Ahmed. Also, how is the right hand limit clearer than the left hand one?

Comment: @DonAntonio : Before your comment I submitted an edit, but seems that it has disappeared. I don't understand.

Comment: I rejected it, Arjang. Read the reasons why.

Comment: @DonAntonio:Thank you I did not know the Rules of Posts

Comment: Oh, they are not "rules", @Ahmed: it's just some little advices for the posts to look nicer, that's all.

Comment: @DonAntonio : I don't know where the reasons are, where can I find them?

Comment: @Arjang: Go to your profile, click "activity" and "suggestions". Find the approriate suggested edit and click it.